# "Initialization segment misses expected aac track." even audio initial segment is appended

Tags: javascript, mpeg-dash, media-source

I am currently working on playing media using DASH and met a problem when playing 2-track (video & audio) media.

Now I have a dash manifest like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xx xx>
  <Period id="0" start="PT0S">
    <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" mimeType="video/mp4" startWithSAP="1">
      <SegmentTemplate initialization="videoInitialFragmentUrl" timescale="1000" startNumber="19" media="someTemplateUrl">
        <SegmentTimeline>
          <S t="37968" d="1994" />
          <S d="2067" />
        </SegmentTimeline>
      </SegmentTemplate>
      <Representation id="video" bandwidth="492421" width="1920" height="1080" frameRate="14.99" codecs="avc1.4d4028" scanType="progressive"/>
    </AdaptationSet>
    <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1">
      <SegmentTemplate initialization="audioInitialFragmentUrl" timescale="1000" startNumber="19" media="someTemplateUrl">
        <SegmentTimeline>
          <S t="37968" d="1994"/>
          <S d="2067" />
        </SegmentTimeline>
      </SegmentTemplate>
      <Representation id="audio" bandwidth="64633" audioSamplingRate="8000" codecs="alaw">
        <AudioChannelConfiguration xx xx/>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
  </Period>
</MPD>
```

I initialize the souceBuffer with following steps:

1. create a mediaSouce with mimeType "video/mp4; codecs=
   avc1.4d0020, mp4a.40.2"
2. create a sourceBuffer and add it to the mediaSource
3. fetch ArrayBuffer from audioInitialFragmentUrl & audioInitialFragmentUrl, and concatenate them.
4. append the buffer to sourceBuffer

And then I got the error "Initialization segment misses expected aac track" but I am pretty sure the buffer contains audio part I fetched from audioInitialFragmentUrl.
Any help about reason?

Answer (score 1):

A single SourceBuffer created for multiplexed content requires a single initialisation segment containing initialisation information for both tracks - you have two initialisation segments each with a single track, so you get this error.

You need to have seperate SourceBuffers - one for each adaptationset.